# SQL question changing the data table's output

Tags: sql-server

So I'm trying to change the output of the table using query without changing the data itself like this.

This is the output I have:

[image]

And this is the output I need to have:

[image]

Comment: Create a new table with lookup values and `JOIN` to that? `ALTER` the table and add a computed column? Use a `CASE` expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```sql
SELECT id,
       CASE pos WHEN 'C' THEN 'Center'
                WHEN 'F' THEN 'Forward'
                WHEN 'G' THEN 'Guard'
                WHEN 'PG' THEN 'Point Guard'
                WHEN 'PF' THEN 'Power Forward'
                WHEN 'SF' THEN 'Shooting Forwad'
                WHEN 'SG' THEN 'Shooting Guard'
        END
FROM    myable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a lookup/mapping table, then just join to that to get your description:

```
create table MyTableMapping (Pos varchar(2), Description varchar(20));

insert into MyTableMapping (Pos, Description)
values
('C' , 'Center'          ),
('F' , 'Forward'         ),
('G' , 'Guard'           ),
('PG', 'Point Guard'     ),
('PF', 'Power Forward'   ),
('SF', 'Shooting Forwad' ),
('SG', 'Shooting Guard'  );

select m.description as Position
from t join MyTableMapping m on m.pos=t.pos;
```